# python multiprocessing within a for loop. How to improve efficiency

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I have this code to solve an embarrassingly parallel problem.
After I compute the solution for a `beta, alpha, range(deltas)` I would like to compute the mean of the results and save it to a dictionary.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import multiprocessing as mtp
import time
from tqdm import tqdm

start = time.time()
def derivative(X, t, alpha, beta, delta, gamma):
    x, y = X
    dotx = x * (alpha - beta * y)
    doty = y * (-delta + gamma * x)
    return np.array([dotx, doty])


gamma = 1.
x0 = 4.
y0 = 2.

Nt = 1000
tmax = 30.
t = np.linspace(0.,tmax, Nt)
X0 = [x0, y0]

betas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.1)
alphas = np.arange(0.9, 1.4, 0.1)
deltas = np.arange(1, 1.2, 0.01)
# paramlist = list(itertools.product(alphas, betas, deltas))

columns = {"time": t}

def function(params):
    alpha, beta, delta = params

    try:
        res = integrate.odeint(derivative, X0, t, args = (alpha, beta, delta, gamma), atol=1e-9, rtol=1e-9)
    except SystemError:
        # fallback values
        x = -1
        y = -1
        print(f"I have an error for alpha: {alpha}, beta: {beta}")

    return res
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nProcess = 8
    
    for beta in betas:
        for alpha in alphas:
            paramlist = list(itertools.product((alpha,), (beta,), deltas))
            with mtp.Pool(processes= nProcess) as pool:
                    results = list( tqdm( pool.imap(function, paramlist), total=len(paramlist)))
                    
        
            calc = np.mean(results, axis=0)
            columns[str(beta) + '_' + str(alpha) + '_x'] = calc[:, 0]
            columns[str(beta) + '_' + str(alpha) + '_y'] = calc[:, 1]
                
                
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
    df.to_pickle("test.pickle")
```

However, the code run really slow. I think parallelization is not efficient with the for loops I have placed. How can I improve this code to compute faster?

Kind regards!

Comment: Try setting `pool.imap(.., chunksize=SOMETHING_LARGER)` and/or, if order does not matter, use `pool.imap_unordered()` instead. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) as well.

Comment: Are you sure you want to create a new pool for every iteration over two nested loops?

Comment: As @KlausD.suggests you should creating and closing pools is not the best way to go. Maybe creating a list of parameters to use before the parallelization would help.

Comment: @KlausD. I have no need to create a new pool every ieteration. I just don't know how to do it better :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs of Pool.imap():

```
Equivalent of `map()` -- can be MUCH slower than `Pool.map()`.
```

When I ran your code as-is on my M1 Pro MBP:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 15.20it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 14.92it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.07it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.94it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 13.46it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.77it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 13.39it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.01it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 10.42it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.16it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.96it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.58it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.03it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.40it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.36it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.47it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.18it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 13.04it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.98it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 12.87it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 10.74it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.86it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.56it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 13.26it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:01<00:00, 11.56it/s]
```

VS when I ran it using pool.map instead of pool.imap:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 524288.00it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 537731.28it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 776722.96it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 162569.92it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 883011.37it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 322638.77it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 873813.33it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 742354.69it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 704925.04it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 334207.49it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 317750.30it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 278691.30it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 103054.15it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 570653.61it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 371177.35it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 490561.87it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 377865.23it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 212908.83it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 830555.25it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 873813.33it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 776722.96it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 710898.98it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 243148.06it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 682000.65it/s]
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 20/20 [00:00<00:00, 769597.06it/s]
```

The individual loops are finishing about as fast as the progress bar appears, now. That said, there's a bit of latency between each loop. <strike>I'm guessing this is due to the np.mean() call and not the itertools.product() call, but suffice it to say this is already so many orders of magnitude faster on my machine that further optimization is probably not necessary.</strike> Nevermind, see below

Edit: On second thought, it could also be because you're instantiating a new pool every loop. I'll keep experimenting.

Edit 2: Yes, okay, I reorganized the main function thusly:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nProcess = 8
    with mtp.Pool(processes=nProcess) as pool:
        for beta in betas:
            for alpha in alphas:
                paramlist = list(itertools.product((alpha,), (beta,), deltas))

                results = list(
                    tqdm(pool.map(function, paramlist), total=len(paramlist))
                )

                calc = np.mean(results, axis=0)
                columns[str(beta) + "_" + str(alpha) + "_x"] = calc[:, 0]
                columns[str(beta) + "_" + str(alpha) + "_y"] = calc[:, 1]

    df = pd.DataFrame(columns)
    df.to_pickle("test.pickle")
```

And now the entire function runs in the blink of an eye. No latency between loops whatsoever.

imap is able to be more memory-efficient than map if you're using an iterable that isn't already all in RAM at once, but since you're passing in a `list` already and not lazy-loading, map is faster and uses the same amount of RAM

Comment: I cannot find any the first quote [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap). Can you link to the source of the quote?

Comment: FWIW, note that one of the main differences is that `chunksize` for `imap` defaults to the very bad 1 but for `map` to `None`, meaning automatic detection. Most likely choosing a sensible chunksize – basically everything above 10 – should be a notable improvement for `imap` as well.

Comment: Sure, [here you go](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L398) @MisterMiyagi

Comment: Oh, I agree @MisterMiyagi, but in my local testing even if I used the exact same calculation to get the same chunksize that `map` was using internally for a call to `imap` or `imap_unordered`, regular `map` still outperformed it by 3-4 orders of magnitude

Comment: So `with mtp.Pool(processes=nProcess) as pool:` before the nested for loop is what does the trick? That was an easy change!

Comment: Should I also add a `pool.join()` after each loop to make sure everything is completed and synched? Or is this not necessary? I do not want to take the risk of avering things that are not of the same `alpha, beta` pairs

Comment: My benchmarks show that `list(pool.imap(worker, iterable, chunksize=n))` takes the same time as `pool.map(worker, iterable, chunksize=n)` for a given worker function and *iterable*. Also you have `paramlist = list(itertools.product((alpha,), (beta,), deltas))`. If you are using `imap`, there is no need to convert the `product` generator into a list; it's length will be the length of `deltas`, which should be computed once. The length of the `deltas` you are using is 20 and with a pool size of 8 your computed *chunksize* will be 1. (more...)

Comment: Since you are computing the mean of the results, then you do not really care what order your worker function completes its calculation. So you should be using `imap_unordered`, which can be faster than `imap` and is preferable if using with a progress bar since the progress bar will advance as soon as your worker function completes work on any of the submitted tasks. If the first task submitted to the pool's task queue happened to be the last one to complete, using `imap` your progress bar will not advance until that first submitted task completes and then it will go to 100% in one step.

Comment: **"Should I also add a `pool.join()` after each loop to make sure everything is completed and synched?"** No! If you are converting the iterator returned from `imap` into a list, that by definition iterates the iterator completely and you know that all submitted tasks have been completed. You can only call `pool.join()` after calling `pool.close()` or `pool.terminate()` and if you call those you can no longer submit tasks to the pool.

Comment: So, this order of the code will guagantee that my code runs as: `(beta1, alpha1, range of delta) -> perform average and save to dicts -> (beta1, alpha2, range of delta) -> so on` There is no risk of me getting mixed up parameters during the processing. Right?

Comment: Regarding the 20 deltas, this is for a test case. In practice I am going to use 2000 deltas. Which should coupe woth the having bigger chunksize. Altough, I am not sure how to set this parameter

Comment: @R.Smith For that use-case you would want to use imap_unordered like @Booboo said in their earlier comments. 

To summarize:
`paramlist = itertools.product((alpha,), (beta,), deltas)`, don't make this a list

and when you call pool.imap_unordered with the chunksize parameter, it would look like this:

`results = list(pool.imap_unordered(function, paramlist, chunksize=100))`

I skipped using tqdm here since you'd need to iterate over paramlist twice (once to get the len and again to use it in imap_unordered), causing unnecessary recalculation. If you need tqdm just use a list and `map`

Comment: It would be nice to have the progress bar. To my understanding the `imap_unordered` will lunch the task as they are completed, not in the order they are issued. Is this correct? Why does `tqdm` need to iterate over `paramlist` twice? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @R.Smith If you were to have paramlist as a raw iterator, calling `len(paramlist)` for tqdm's `total` arg would cause it to perform a full iteration, whereas calling `len(paramlist)` on paramlist *as a list* would simply check the len of the list as an O(1) operation, basically free since the full list is in RAM already.